# How insert SMS logs to samsung S4 android device

Tags: android, logging, sms, android-contentprovider, samsung-mobile

I'm trying to make backup & restore my call log.

I'm able to read the sms log from uri "content://logs/historys".

But when I insert back the data, then return value is null and nothing is added into database.

My code (for api 17, 4.2.2 version):

```
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put("type","1");
     values.put("formatted_number", "+420 775 xxx xxx"); // consored
     values.put("number", "+420775xxxxxx"); // censored
     values.put("geocoded_location", "Ceská republika");
     values.put("date", "1436527300000");
     values.put("name", "xxxxx xxxxxxxxx"); // censored
     values.put("normalized_number", "+420775xxxxxx"); // censored
     values.put("logtype", "300");
     values.put("m_content", "Test");
     values.put("countryiso", "CZ");
     values.put("numbertype", "2");
     values.put("new", "0");
     values.put("duration", "0");
     values.put("e164_number", "+420775xxxxxx");  // censored ;-)

     getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://logs/historys"), values);
```

I have also these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.logsprovider.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.logsprovider.permission.WRITE_LOGS" />
```

when I look into logcat, then there is no exception or record about failure.

And question is, **how I can insert this sms log record back into the database?**

Thanks for an idea! :)